# Двойная скобка борется с одинарной

Tags: орфография

Как я прочитал, в русском нет чёткого предписание, которое бы говорило, нужно ли одну или все две скобки в конце или в начале ставить, когда в конструкции, заключённой в скобки, появляется другая, которая тоже в скобках таки. Однако я хочу, совы, узнать, как лучше по узусу писать лучше: с одной (1.) или в двумя (2.).

P. S.  Я всё время с двумя писал, и я насчёт этого до вчерашнего дне не сомневался, а вчера я в учебнике Лопатина увидел, что он только одну в похожем случае использовать, и поэтому начал я таки сомневаться, а я хочу писать по узусу.

1. Это была женщина (старая, честно говоря (как Баба-яга), и она была плохая.
2. Это была женщина (старая, честно говоря (как Баба-яга)), и она была плохая.

Вот фото из справочника Лопатина, где видно, что тольно одна скобка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Добавлю материал** из [ПАС под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp58.php)

Исключения: причастия брезжущий (от брезжить, брезжит) и зиждущий(ся) (от зиждить(ся) пишутся с суффиксом -ущ-.

Comment: Узус — это не только орфография и пунктуация. Это ещё правильное употребление. Эта информация не для скобок, она основная, не дополнительная. Идёт наравне со следующей: *старая и плохая*. И там и там характеристика. Вы неправильно употребляете скобки. "Как Баба-яга" вообще не для скобок, чисто ошибка употребления.

Comment: @Pumpkin777 *Однако я хочу, совы, узнать, как **лучше** по узусу писать **лучше**: с одной **(1.)** или в двумя **(2.)**.* Зачем нам два раза "лучше"? И зачем точечки внутри скобок?

Comment: У вас интересная логическая ошибка. Фото не из справочника, а справочника. Фото же не в справочнике находилось... Ну и здесь больше подходит слово "скриншот".

Comment: Потом ещё момент. То, что в скобках, не отрывается от слова, к которому относится. "Как Баба-яга" относится к "старая", а вы разрываете вводным.

Comment: @Pumpkin777 «P. S. Я всё время с двумя писал, и я насчёт этого до вчерашнего дне не сомневался, а вчера я в учебнике Лопатина увидел, что он только одну в похожем случае использовать, и поэтому начал я таки сомневаться, а я хочу писать по узусу», — пишете и не даёте себе труда править. Перечитайте эту стилизацию под лубок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** [Сочетания знаков препинания. Скобки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=179#pp179) (Розенталь, § 67.4):

> **4.** При «встрече» в конце предложения внутренних и внешних скобок допускается употребление скобок разного рисунка — круглых (внутренние) и квадратных (внешние).

**2.** [Знаки препинания при вставках](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128) (Лопатин, § 100):

> Примечание. Скобки графически варьируются: круглые (), фигурные {}, квадратные [ ], угловые < >. Наиболее распространены круглые скобки; фигурные скобки употребляются только в специальных текстах (например, математических). Квадратные скобки применяются для авторского пояснения отдельных слов в цитируемом тексте: *Он* [Блок] *первым открыл талант Есенина, первым услышал «песни души» рязанского поэта* (Ю. Прокушев).
>
> Квадратные скобки могут сочетаться с круглыми в условиях двойного выделения (квадратные скобки — для внешнего выделения, круглые — для внутреннего выделения): *Виргинские острова, группа мелких о-вов в Вест-Индии. Владение Великобритании [153,4 км2, нас. 13т. ч. (1984);адм. ц. — Род-Таун]и США [344 км2, 101 т. ч. (1984); адм. ц. — Шарлотта-Амалия] (БЭС. М., 1991)*.

**3.** [Ответы "Грамоты"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8):

> • В правилах пунктуации предписаний по поводу двойных скобок нет. Конструкции, которые нуждаются в двух парах скобок, нежелательны. Часто можно заменить одну пару скобок на тире. Однако иногда двойные скобки встречаются в специальных текстах, например в академических правилах орфографии...
>
> • Двойные скобки избегаются, лучше использовать скобки разного рисунка: (...[...]).
>
> • Вторая скобка, как правило, не ставится.

•• **Решение-обобщение**
Ни в первом, ни во втором правиле об опускании одной из скобок и слова нет.
Откуда "Грамота" взяла конструкцию **(...[...])** и рекомендацию скобку не ставить — неизвестно.

Никакой борьбы между одинарной и двойной скобкой не вижу. В правиле Лопатина, скорее всего, "недопечатка", кочующая из издания в издание (таких случаев — предостаточно).

Если нет возможности избежать ситуации с двойными скобками, то мы их все-таки пишем:

> Примечание 2. О типах слов, входящих в географическое название: 1) существительные, значение которых не соответствует роду названного географического объекта (*Голодная Губа* (озеро)), 2) несамостоятельные иноязычные родовые наименования (*Рио-Гранде* (*рио* ‘река’)), 3) существительные с уменьш. суф., образованные от родовых наименований (*Красное Озерко* (озеро)); 4) существительные, называющие титулы, звания, профессии, должности и под. (*Адмирала Кузнецова* (хребет))...

А вот в вашем предложении вторые скобки вообще не нужны (если есть возможность — а она есть, — избегаем их, избегаем): *(старая, честно говоря, как Баба-яга)*.

••• **Из моего опыта**
Если мне надо указать и автора произведения, и обозначить год написания, то я это делаю таким образом:
(Владимир Мукусев, Анастасия Ниточкина. Взгляд изнутри // «Огонек». № 1 (3311), **1991**);
(Александр Чаковский. Блокада (**1968**));
(Сергей Довлатов. Компромисс (**1981–1984**)).

•••• **Дополнительные ссылки**
[Двойные скобки](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8/)
[Названия природных географических объектов](https://orfo.ruslang.ru/rules/rule/4)

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что лучше квадратные внутри. Квадратные для того, что поменьше...

Comment: Логика следующая: сначала используем обычные, а потом видим, что ещё одни нужны, и используем уже другие. (Если говорить об использовании разных скобок.)

Comment: Ну да, конечно... Это если следовать *логике*. Но и у Розенталя, и у Лопатина, если напрямую следовать правилам, — **[... (...)]**.

Comment: Ещё важен сам текст. Для года больше подходят обычные, для математических и табличных данных подходят квадратные (близки по духу математике), что и в примерах. Им следовало обратить на это внимание. А обычного текста там нет.

Comment: Ну вот... Хоть в чем-то Вы со мной соглашаетесь. P. S. Спасибо за указание на описку. Объем ответа получился большим — сразу все "обпечатки" и не заметишь.

Comment: Ну это вне того, что вы написали (не то чтобы прочитал и согласился). А вы перестали неправильно отвечать (не то что некоторые). Так держать! Больше осторожности, больше обоснования — и не будет неправильных ответов (не вам конкретно, а в общем). А желание исправлять мелочи — это очень классно (кое-кому надо брать пример). Меня вот чуть ли не трясёт, если ошибка в комментарии, исправить-то потом нельзя. А я проверяю в реальном времени, поэтому опечатки крайне редко (когда меняю в середине и что-то не подстраиваю). То есть пишу и одновременно проверяю (даже в процессе печатания слова).